# Como descartar elementos duplicados de una lista dentro de otra en python?

Tags: python, lista, algoritmos

Lo que deseo es conformar una lista con datos de clientes que descarte aquellos que están duplicados:

Ejemplo de una telefónica:

```
clientes = [['Enrique', 3724002567], ['Andrés', 3924062327], ['Colon', 36249023945], ['Mauro', 3684309752], ['Solci', 3644026449], ['Mauro', 35242639589], ['Solci', 3621596563], ['Enrique', 36245524]]
```

En dicha lista hay clientes duplicados debido a que poseen otro número telefónico.

Lo que quiero hacer es conformar una lista que solo contenga listas con un nombre y un número telefónico único, y descartar todo aquel nombre duplicado

Es decir que quede así:

```
clientes = [['Enrique', 3724002567], ['Andrés', 3924062327], ['Colon', 36249023945], ['Mauro', 3684309752], ['Solci', 3644026449]]
```

Gracias

Comment: Cambia la lista a un diccionario con nombres como llaves.

Comment: sería bueno que indicaras qué has intentado. Recomiendo leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Quiero comenzar haciendo algunas observaciones como la estructura del objeto, es bastante mala para lo que buscas conseguir, te recomiendo trabajar directamente con diccionarios cuando necesites `clave / valor`.

Respecto al código te recomiendo que verifiques bien el modelo de negocios para eliminar duplicados, si estos tendrán valores diferentes realmente la forma en que los eliminas puede ser un dolor de cabeza. ¿Necesitas dejar la clave con el ultimo valor encontrado? ¿Necesitas dejar la clave con el primer valor encontrado? ¿Es posible reemplazar una clave de nombre por un identificador unico?

```
import pprint
clientes = [['Enrique', 3724002567], ['Andrés', 3924062327], ['Colon', 36249023945], ['Mauro', 3684309752], ['Solci', 3644026449], ['Mauro', 35242639589], ['Solci', 3621596563], ['Enrique', 36245524]]
def duplicates_information(elements):
    output = []
    temp_key = []
    duplicates = []
    for element in elements:
        if element[0] in temp_key:
            duplicates.append(element)
        else:
            temp_key.append(element[0])
            output.append(element)
    return {"output" : output, "duplicates" : duplicates, "all_elements" : elements}

info = duplicates_information(clientes)
pprint.pprint(info)
```